# Circle CI 2.0 Rails Redis Resque - Rspec Redis Server Not Found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, redis, circleci

When our test suite runs we are getting the following issue regarding redis-server. No matter what we have tried, nothing seems to get past this error.  We have validated via dockerize that the containers are live by waiting as seen below, but this error still occurs.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

**Resque Initializer**

```
require 'resque'
require 'redis'
require 'yaml'

# Resque Plugins
require 'resque/plugins/retry'
require 'resque-retry'
require 'resque-retry/server'
require 'resque-lock-timeout'
require 'resque-scheduler'
require 'resque/failure/multiple'
require 'resque/failure/redis'
require 'resque-job-stats/server'
require 'resque/rollbar'

if AppUnsecure.settings[:active_db_services].include?('redis')
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
  config = {
    host: uri.host,
    port: uri.port,
    password: uri.password
  }
  Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [ Resque::Failure::Redis, Resque::Failure::Rollbar ]
  Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(config)
elsif AppUnsecure.settings[:active_db_services].include?('redis-continous-integration')
  Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis]
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(host: 'redis://localhost', port: 6391)
else
  Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis]
  Resque.redis = Redis.new
end

Resque.redis.namespace = 'resque:GathrlySmartforms'

# Ignores Resque when processing jobs if activated!
Resque.inline = true if AppUnsecure.settings[:process_redis_inline]

# Setup Scheduler
# https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/118
# https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/issues/581
Resque::Scheduler.configure do |c|
  c.quiet = false
  c.verbose = false
  c.logfile = File.join(Rails.root, 'log', "#{Rails.env}_resque_scheduler.log")
  c.logformat = 'text'
end
Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true

schedules = {}
global = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
schedules.merge!(global) if global
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158226/how-do-i-skip-loading-of-rails-initializers-when-running-a-rake-task
unless defined?(is_running_migration?) && is_running_migration?
  Resque.schedule = schedules if schedules.present?
end

Resque::Server.class_eval do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    [username, password] == [Rails.application.secrets.my_resque_username, Rails.application.secrets.my_resque_password]
  end
end
```

**Circle Configuration**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/DIR_NAME
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1-node
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: continous_integration
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: rails_test_user

      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6.3-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: rails_test_user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
          POSTGRES_DB: continous_integration

      - image: redis:4.0.6

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Dockerize v0.6.0
          command: |
            wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/v0.6.0/dockerize-linux-amd64-v0.6.0.tar.gz
            sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/dockerize
            sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-v0.6.0.tar.gz
            rm dockerize-linux-amd64-v0.6.0.tar.gz

      - run:
          name: Wait for PG
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 2m

      - run:
          name: Wait for Redis
          command: |
            dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:6379 -timeout 2m

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - DIR_NAME-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - DIR_NAME-

      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      - run:
          name: Setup Bundler and Gems
          command: |
            gem install bundler
            gem update bundler
            gem install brakeman
            gem install rubocop
            gem install rubocop-rspec
            gem install scss_lint
            gem install eslint-rails
            gem install execjs
            bundle config without development:test
            bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --without development test --path=vendor/bundle --jobs 4 --retry 3

      - run:
          name: Install Phantom Js
          command: |
            sudo curl --output /tmp/phantomjs https://s3.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1
            sudo chmod ugo+x /tmp/phantomjs
            sudo ln -sf /tmp/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs

      - run:
          name: Install Postgres Tools
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

      - run:
          name: Install Redis Tools
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install redis-tools ; while ! redis-cli ping 2>/dev/null ; do sleep 1 ; done

      - run:
          name: Build Rails Database Yaml
          command: |
            cp config/database_example.yml config/database.yml

      - run:
          name: Setup Rails Database
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:drop
            bundle exec rake db:setup

      - run:
          name: Run Rspec
          timeout: 60
          command: |
            RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter -o /tmp/test-results/rspec.xml

      - run:
          name: Run Brakeman
          command: |
            brakeman -z

      - run:
          name: Run Rubocop
          command: |
            bundle exec rubocop --format fuubar --require rubocop-rspec --config .rubocop.yml

      - run:
          name: Run the SCSS Linter
          command: |
            bundle exec scss-lint --config=config/scsslint.yml

      - run:
          name: Run the Eslint Linter for JS
          command: |
            bundle exec rake eslint:run_all


      - store_test_results:
          path: /tmp/test-results
```

**UPDATE**

On various test runs it may occasionally work...however, the error is still the same, this must be the cause...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what *Postgres connects to redis fine* means exactly.  The postgres user like through redis-cli?  Postgres isn't connecting directly is it? (foreign data wrapper -- just read up on this ... I didn't even know you could do that, wow).  Well, nevermind, that's sort of a tangent ...

Some minor insight, I can't test this whole thing very easily ... the PID file not being that is probably because it's just dying.  The `kill: invalid argument Q` is probably from something doing `kill -QUIT`.  This could be in redis' scripts or something.  I bet the process is already dead and kill is just erroring out poorly.  I think kill really wants the PID to exist.  Although I just tested this and this is NOT how this works.  So maybe Circle has non-GNU coreutils installed or something?

I don't think `POSTGRES_USER` should be in the redis image.  See this example: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/circleci-bug-for-builds-with-redis/13124  Looks like things changed with 2.0.

If the gist has been updated to a completely new config, update the error messages and problem too, unless it's the same.

Comment: The question has been updated with more data, do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like the resque initializer really wants a `REDIS_URL` set.  I don't see that anywhere.  But that wouldn't cause your problem!  I ran `/bin/bash` from the 4.0.6 docker image and yeah `redis-server` is in the path.  Hey, how about something really lazy like changing the sleep from `1` to `10` and seeing if the inconsistency disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what we can tell from here, it seems that your configuration is referencing a redis process that does not exist in test.

Also you're bundling without test. Not sure why.

Can you post your Redis configuration file? <- Still need this.

You need to configure REDIS_URL to the docker image.

Comment: The question has been updated with more data, do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: The redis process that is starting does not have a pid named redis-test. This is a redis configuration error. It's looking for an instance of redis running locally to the application and there is not one.